# Fortran - problem with double precision

Tags: fortran

I have a small program that read some data from binary file and stores it into normal (unformatted) files. Here is the source:

```
  Program calki2e
  IMPLICIT NONE
!
       DOUBLE PRECISION VAL
      INTEGER P,Q,R,S
    INTEGER  IREC2C
      PARAMETER( IREC2C=15000)
      INTEGER  AND,RSHIFT,LABEL,IMBABS,NX,IB,NFT77
      INTEGER  IND
      DIMENSION IND(IREC2C)
    DOUBLE PRECISION  XP
      DIMENSION XP(IREC2C)
      CHARACTER(LEN=12) :: FN77 = 'input08'
    CONTINUE
    NFT77=77
!----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   CONTINUE
c
    open(unit=NFT77,file=FN77,STATUS='OLD',
     +ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL',FORM='UNFORMATTED')
    open(unit=13,file='calki2e.txt')
    REWIND(77)
4100    continue
     READ(77) NX,IND,XP
       IMBABS=IABS(NX)
       DO 100 IB=1,IMBABS
            LABEL=IND(IB)
            P= AND(RSHIFT(LABEL, 24),255)
            Q= AND(RSHIFT(LABEL, 16),255)
            R= AND(RSHIFT(LABEL,  8),255)
            S= AND(       LABEL     ,255)
            VAL=XP(ib)  
            IF(P.EQ. Q) VAL=VAL+VAL                               
            IF(R .EQ. S)  VAL=VAL+VAL                                    
            IF((P .EQ. R).AND.(Q .EQ. S)) VAL=VAL+VAL 
    write(13,*)P,Q,R,S,val
100 CONTINUE
    IF (NX.GT.0) GOTO 4100
CRB
      CLOSE(UNIT=NFT77)
!
    END
```

When I compile it using gfortran I obtain double precision in output file but with g77 I get only single precision. What it wrong and how to change it?

Comment: you are going to have to adjust your code formatting before anyone can read this. Indent code by 4 spaces to have it render properly.

Comment: You should format your post better; use code blocks for your code.

Comment: I have reformmated your code. Select the code and use the 100 button to do this

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the "write (13, *) statement.   This is "list directed" output.   It is a convenience I/O with few rules -- what you get will depend upon the compiler -- it is best used for debugging and "quick and dirty" programs.   To reliably get all the digits of double precision, change to a formatted output statement, specifying the number of digits that you need.   (It is probably best to switch to gfortran anyway, as g77 is no longer under development.)

Answer (score 0):

your numbers are double precision but you are printing them in free format. You have to specify an explicit format

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to set the format on your write statement to something explicit, rather than use `* in write(13,*)P,Q,R,S,val`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code F77, try something like

```
      write(13,1000) P,Q,R,S,val
1000  format(1X,4I7,1X,1E14.10)
```

The "1X"s mean one space, "4I7" means four seven-width integers, and 1E14.10 means one fourteen-charater width scientific-notation real number with 10 significant digits.  Feel free to mess around with the numbers to get it to look right.

[This](http://www.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/17_format.html) is a pretty good tutorial on the topic.